# Recursion: How does this program work?

Tags: arrays, recursion

I'm doing recursion exercises and I understand the basics of it. But this one exercise has me stuck and I have no idea how it got to it's output. Here it is:

```
public class MinIndex_rec
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] a = {1, -16, -3, 4, -5, -12, -17};
      System.out.println("The Min value index is: " + MinIndex(a, a.length - 1));
   }

   public static int MinIndex(int[] x, int n)
   {
      if(n == 0)
         return n;

      int index = MinIndex(x, n-1);

      if(x[index]<x[n])
      {
         System.out.println(x[index] + "\t" + x[n] + "\t" + index + "\t" + n);
         return index;
      }

      else
         return n;     
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
-16 -3 1 2
-16 4 1 3
-16 -5 1 4
-16 -12 1 5
The Min value Index is: 6
```

I just have no clue on how it got to that output. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes something like this:

```
x = {1, -16, -3, 4, -5, -12, -17};

MinIndex(x, 6)
  if(n == 0) => false
  index = MinIndex(x, 5)

    if(n == 0) => false
    index = MinIndex(x, 4)

    ...

      index = MinIndex(x, 0)      // this is called when n is 1, x[n] = -16
      if(n == 0) => true          // True here so return 0
        => index = 0
      if(x[0]<x[1]) => false      // False here so return n again to the call
                                  // when n was 2
        => index = 1
        => if(x[1]<x[2]) => TRUE
        => System.out.println(-16 + "\t" + -3 + "\t" + 1 + "\t" + 2);
        ...
        etc.
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! This makes it much easier to understand. Two questions though, after it's determined n == 0 is false, why does it go to (x, 5) and so on until it gets to 0, instead of continuing on? And then when you get to x[0] < x[1], which is false, you go to the next instance where x[index] < x[n]?

Comment: @whosbrucewayne if `n == 0` is false, it goes to the next statement in the code, which is `int index = MinIndex(x, n-1);` calling MinIndex with `n-1`. Until `n == 0` is true and then `index` gets assigned that returned call. At that point `index` equals `0` and `n` equals `1` so we go to the next statement `if(x[0]<x[1])` but that's false as well, so we go to `else return n`, but this is returning to the earlier function call when `n` was `2`. So once again `index` gets assigned `1` and the comparison `x[1] < x[2]` is true so the line is printed.

Comment: @whosbrucewayne the function calls do continue on after the recursive call, but first the recursive call is completed since the function is relying on the return value.

Comment: I understand it now!! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The method recursively finds the item with lowest index in the array.

The method accepts two parameters - the array and its maximum index to check. It then recursively calls itself on the subset of that array - basically one element shorter. It uses the result to compare the element at the returned position to the element at the highest position (the one which was not included in the recursive call evaluation). Depending whether the element at the highest position is greater or not, it returns the highest position as the index of the maximum element or the original index returned from the subset.

The first four rows in the example just return temporary result, i.e. the maximum element index for the subset of the original array - the first element, first three elements, first four elements etc.

This debug message is printed only when the highest value doesn't change. So in this specific example it always prints 1 as it doesn't change except the first and the very last comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I'm still a little confused, I think mainly from int index = MinIndex(x, n-1). Why does it always end up 1?